# indefinite article usage: "a thing of something can be found here" vs. "the thing of something can be found here"

Tags: grammar, articles, indefinite-articles

I had an argument with my colleague about the usage of the indefinite article in this sentence:

> this system uses OAuth 2 as an authentication scheme, a documentation of the authentication service can be found here:

his argument was that the use of `a documentation` is wrong because we're talking about a specific one here, and that it should be `the documentation`

My argument was that we mentioned the documentation for the first time here, and it should be indefinite.

Which one is correct? please provider a reference/evidence if possible.

Answer (score 1):

The choice of *definite* vs. *indefinite* is not down to whether this is the first time it's been mentioned, but whether you are referring to a specific thing whose identity is known (see Rule #2 of [**Definite and Indefinite Articles (a, an, the)**](http://www.butte.edu/departments/cas/tipsheets/grammar/articles.html)). In this case, although you've only just mentioned the documentation, it is a specific thing that *you* know the identity of, even if the reader doesn't (yet) know of that document.

If there are *multiple* documentations of the service (not just multiple copies of the same document, but multiple different documents) with the others to be found *there*, *there* and *there*, then *a documentation* could be correct (though it still would sound strange).

Assuming there is one document that documents the service, then you would use "*the documentation*".